# How does rails v6 fills REQUEST's content-length when a client doesn't send content-length in the headers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, node-fetch

Long story short, I am using node-fetch to upload a file to a Rails server.
The file is from `fs.createReadStream` = ReadStream.

https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch

> Note: when body is a Stream, Content-Length is not set automatically.

As it says in the readme, when it's a stream, the request's content-length will not be set by node-fetch.

- When receiving the data with Rails v6, it somehow setups the request's content-length even though the client is not sending the length.
- When receiving the same data **with Rails v5, it doesn't** setup the content-length.

I am trying to monkey-patch v5 with what they did in v6.
Does anyone know how v6 does that?

Answer (score 0):

It was actually puma..
https://github.com/puma/puma/pull/2287

it's fixed v4.3.7 and on.
https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/History.md#437--2020-11-30